# C++ to Java code translation : numberToBarcode()

Tags: java, c++, translation

Can someone please help me translate this code from C++ to Java? I have no knowledge in C++.

EDIT2:
Thanks for the responses guys, I will be taking the time to learn C++ soon. I just needed some help translating things. Here is my finished translation. I am getting errors for the all of the numberToBarcode() method names.  Could I get you guys to check this code for me to see if the translation is accurate?

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zipBar {
public static int numberToBarcode(int arg0)
{
    return arg0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int z;
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, checkNum;
    int tempNum;
    int checkTotal;
    String barcode = "|";

    System.out.println("Enter zip code: ");
    Scanner zip = new Scanner(System.in);
    z = zip.nextInt(); 

    if (z >= 10000 || z < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Input Error: Input not a valid zip code");

    }
    tempNum = z;

    num5 = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum = tempNum / 10;

    num4 = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum = tempNum / 10;

    num3 = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum = tempNum / 10;

    num2 = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum = tempNum / 10;

    num1 = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum = tempNum / 10;

    checkTotal = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
    checkNum = (10-(checkTotal % 10)) % 10;

    barcode += numberToBarcode(num1);
    barcode += numberToBarcode(num2);  
    barcode += numberToBarcode(num3);  
    barcode += numberToBarcode(num4);  
    barcode += numberToBarcode(num5);  
    barcode += numberToBarcode(checkNum);

    barcode += "|";

    System.out.println("Your zip code's barcode is: " + barcode);

    //return 0;

}

public static void String numberToBarcode(int num){

String barcode = " ";

int dig;
int tempNum;
int bcTotal = 0;

tempNum = num;

if (tempNum >= 10){
    dig = tempNum % 10;
    tempNum /= 10;

    barcode = numberToBarcode(tempNum);
}
else{
    dig = tempNum;
}
tempNum = dig;

if (dig == 0) {
    barcode += "||:::";
}
else{
    if (tempNum / 7 == 1 && bcTotal < 2){
        barcode += "|";
        tempNum -= 7;
        bcTotal++;
    }
    else  
        barcode += ":";   
    if (tempNum / 4 == 1 && bcTotal < 2) {     
        barcode += "|";  
        tempNum -= 4;  
        bcTotal++;  
    } else  
        barcode += ":";  
    if (tempNum / 2 == 1 && bcTotal < 2) {    
        barcode += "|";  
        tempNum -= 2;  
        bcTotal++;  
    } else  
        barcode += ":";  
    if (tempNum / 1 == 1 && bcTotal < 2) {  
        barcode += "|";  
        tempNum -= 1;  
        bcTotal++;  
    } else  
        barcode += ":";  
    if (bcTotal < 2) { 
        barcode += "|";  
        bcTotal++;  
    } else  
        barcode += ":";
}
return barcode;
}

}
```

C++ Code:

```
string numberToBarcode(int);  

int main() {  

int zip;  
int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, checkNum;  
int tempNum;  
int checkTotal;  
string barcode = "|"; 

cout << "Please enter a 5 digit zip code.\n"  
    << " --> ";  
cin >> zip; 


if (zip >= 100000 || zip < 0) {  
    cout << "Error: Not a zip code.\n";  
    return 0;  
}  

tempNum = zip;  

num5 = tempNum % 10;  
tempNum = tempNum / 10;  
num4 = tempNum % 10;  
tempNum = tempNum / 10;  
num3 = tempNum % 10;  
tempNum = tempNum / 10;  
num2 = tempNum % 10;  
tempNum = tempNum / 10;  
num1 = tempNum % 10;  
tempNum = tempNum / 10;  

checkTotal = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;  
checkNum = (10-(checkTotal % 10))%10;   


barcode += numberToBarcode(num1);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it is worth translating by hand Java to C++. You should better learn C++ (which requires a different mindset than Java).

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problem lies. If you know even the basics of Java, you should be able to ask a more specific question, and if you don't, then no answer will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

C++ allows you to just mention the data type `(int)` without following it with a name, but only in function *declarations*, you have to define it in the implementation. Otherwise, there is not much difference in the general syntax (though that doesn't mean you can use the C++ function implementation directly in Java).

Here's a Java translation:

```
/** Java translation **/
String numberToBarcode(int arg0);

barcode += numberToBarcode(num1);  
barcode += numberToBarcode(num2);  
barcode += numberToBarcode(num3);  
barcode += numberToBarcode(num4);  
barcode += numberToBarcode(num5);  

barcode += numberToBarcode(checkNum);
```

Also, if this is the first time you've encountered such a situation, I must inform you that there are hundreds of C++ code-bases that you may have to use or translate into Java in your career. So I advise you to seriously consider learning a bit of C++. It's a pretty good investment.

Comment: could you please look at my code above and see if my translation seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see is that you need to use `String` instead of `string`  You might want to make the method static as well.

```
public static String numberToBarcode(int n) {
   return n as a String
}
```

all the other lines are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface BarcodGenerator {
    String numberToBarcode(int no);
}

BarcodeGenerator bg =.... some instance ....

String barcode = "";
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(num1);
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(num2);
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(num3);
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(num4);
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(num5);
barcode += bg.numberToBarcode(checkNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String numberToBarcode(int x){
    return ""+x;
} 

String makeBarCode() {
    String barcode="";
    barcode += numberToBarcode(1);   
    barcode += numberToBarcode(2);   
    barcode += numberToBarcode(3);   
    barcode += numberToBarcode(4);   
    barcode += numberToBarcode(5);
    return barcode;
}
```